# my DataGridView was not show True Values

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView and its work correctly. But it does not show True False Value. Whats the problem?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1048px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderColor="#663300" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SeatNumber" HeaderText="SeatNumber" SortExpression="SeatNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="customer_id" HeaderText="customer_id" SortExpression="customer_id" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Reserved" HeaderText="Reserved" SortExpression="Reserved" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SeatPrice" HeaderText="SeatPrice" SortExpression="SeatPrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventName" HeaderText="EventName" SortExpression="EventName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="family" HeaderText="family" SortExpression="family" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
    </div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AraratComplexConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.SingleSeatTable.SeatNumber, dbo.SingleSeatTable.customer_id, dbo.SingleSeatTable.Reserved, dbo.Event_SingleReservation.Time, dbo.Event_SingleReservation.Date, 
                  dbo.Event_SingleReservation.SeatPrice, dbo.Event_SingleReservation.EventName, dbo.Registration.name, dbo.Registration.family
FROM         dbo.Registration INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SingleSeatTable ON dbo.Registration.customer_id = dbo.SingleSeatTable.customer_id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Event_SingleReservation ON dbo.SingleSeatTable.EventCode = dbo.Event_SingleReservation.EventCode"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: what values is it showing?

Comment: in the GridView table all value was shown except Reserved . in the sqlserver Reserved for this record has True value but in the gridview table its empty

Comment: is that a bit datatype column in database? If not then you could use checkbox with in item template field and rowdatabound to bind these checkbox with value.

Comment: Do you see the chekboxes inside your GridView but none of them are checked?Is that The problem?What is the data type of the Reserved column in SQL?Is it Bit?Is it NVARCHAR?

Comment: if you mean field checkboxes wich i should check and that checked values was shown in the gridview table , i checked all items . in sqlserver Reserved is bit . but when i click in TestQuery in configure Data...the reserved column show Checked